# Div id to the input value

Tags: html, input, hidden-field

I have a div

```
<div id="force_id"></div>
```

This prints an id for each product on the page. Ex: 26588

How do I assign it to a hidden input value ?

```
<input name="" id="deger" type="hidden" value="<div id="force_id"></div>">
```

Not like of course :=)

Comment: so does it look like `<div id="force_id"> 26588 </div>`?

Comment: No, not like that. Value of their writing According to the product on the page where.  <div id="force_id"></div>  = 38735 for example.

Comment: @Extropy what do you mean `<div id="force_id"></div> = 38735 for example` how does a div equal a number?

Comment: Yes I will post it with ajax. 
var parcel=$("#deger").val();

Comment: @jmore009 This div prints an id for each product on the page. 15423 writes in a page. in another 28763. That variables. It says #force_id

Comment: @Extropy sorry but this is not making any sense. how does a div `print an id`. I think you need to explain further or post more code demonstrating what you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

First off all I think you question ambiguous and what ever you are trying to achieve through this kind of tag might not be a good way to do. I suggest you to **look for alternative ways if possible**.

```
<input name="" id="deger" type="hidden" value="<div id="force_id"></div>">
```

But if you insist this can be easily done. Treat the value like any other string value you would insert inside a div but this time you will need to escape the quote character as below

```
$("#deger").val('<div id=\"force_id\"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#deger').val($('#force_id').text());
```

see the code snippet below

```js
function doIt() {
  $('#deger').val($('#force_id').text());
}

// Just for testing what happens
var degerEl = document.getElementById('deger');
var resultEl = document.getElementById('result');
var doItBtn = document.getElementById('doItBtn');
doItBtn.addEventListener('click', doItOnClickCallback);
setResultElValue();

function doItOnClickCallback() {
  doIt();
  setResultElValue();
}

function setResultElValue() {
  resultEl.value = degerEl.outerHTML;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="" id="deger" type="hidden" value="">
<div id="force_id">26588</div>

<!-- Just for testing what happens -->
<button id="doItBtn">Do it</button><br/>
<textarea readonly id="result" style="font-family:monospace;width:400px"></textarea>
```

---